# Calculate average sea level change

Tags: c

This the assignment I'm trying to do.
Download the sea level data from http://climate.nasa.gov/vital-signs/sea-level (Links to an external site.). Create a program that does the following:

a. Tell the user that the program uses data from NASA to predict sea level from the years 2020 to 2050.

b. Store the sea level data in an array. You only need to use one data point for each year from 1993 to the present year. Use the last column for each row (the Global Mean Sea Level GMSL with annual and semi-annual signal removed).

c. Find the average annual change in sea level over all the years specified in the data. (Hint - use a loop to store the annual change in an array over the years, and then use a loop to compute the average annual change).

d. Assume a linear increase and compute the predicted sea level rise for the years 2020, 2025, 2030, 2035, 2040, 2045, and 2050. Store these results in their own array. (Hint - just use the average you computed in part c as the annual change for the future years).

e. Display the results for the user and be sure to reference the data set as specified in the data file so the user knows where the data came from.

Sample output:

The predicted Global Mean Sea Level is

2020    64.32

2025    68.98

2030    73.51

2035    78.12

2040    83.43

2045    88.12

2050    93.04

These predictions were made using data provided by XXXXXXXXXX

This is the code so far. However It seems to not use all of the data in the array to find the average change in sea level.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
//creates a file object to read data
FILE* infile = fopen("nasa.txt","r");

//checks if file exists
if(infile == NULL)
{
printf("File does not exist.\n");
return -1;
}

//create 2d array to store years and their sea levels
int level[50][2];
//number of elements in array
int n = 0,i;

char word[5];

//read data from file word by word
while(fscanf(infile, "%s", word) != EOF)
{
if(word != ' ' && word != '\n')
{

//convert string to int and store in array
level[n][0] = atoi(word);

//store sea level
fscanf(infile, "%s", word);
level[n][1] = atoi(word);

//increment n
n++;
}
}

//store avg change
float avg=0;

for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
//add difference of consecutive elements
avg += level[i][1] - level[i-1][1];
}

//calculate mean
avg = (float)avg/n;

int c = 7; //number of predictions
//array to store results
float predictions[][2] = {{2020,0},{2025,0},{2030,0},{2035,0},
{2040,0},{2045,0},{2050,0}};


//predict future sea levels
for(i=0;i<c;i++)
{
//multiply avg change by number of years
predictions[i][1] = level[n-1][1] +
(predictions[i][0] - level[n-1][0])*avg;
}

//print avg change
printf("Average change in sea level year over year is: %f mm\n",avg);

//print predictions
for(i = 0;i<c;i++)
{
printf("Predicted sea level change since 1993 for the year %.0f: %.2f mm\n",
predictions[i][0],predictions[i][1]);
}
printf("These predictions were made using data provided by the National Aeronautics and Space Administration.");

return 0;
}
```

Sea level change data

1993 4

1994 7

1995 11

1996 14

1997 21

1998 20

1999 19

2000 22

2001 27

2002 31

2003 34

2004 36

2005 40

2006 42

2007 43

2008 47

2009 48

2010 54

2011 53

2012 59

2013 65

2014 68

2015 75

2016 83

2017 85

2018 88

2019 94

Comment: If a program doesn't work as expected then the best action is to debug the program (and only post on SO as a last resort). What debugging have you done? Suggest you run your program in a debugger and/or add more debug prints to trace its execution. This may also be useful: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: as far as I can tell  this line of code is the problem. (avg += level[i][1] - level[i-1][1];)

Comment: `if(word != ' ' && word != '\n')` make no sense.  Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

> However It seems to not use all of the data in the array to find the average change in sea level.

`avg = (float)avg/n;` is same as `avg = (float)(level[n-1][1] - level[0][1])/n`.

Only the end-points matter.
The loop that accumulates the differences is canceling out the in-between year's values.

In a mid-year, if you add +100, it makes one year difference +100 more, and the next year difference 100 less.  The running sum of the differences is not affect by that +100 in the end.

All the mid-year values could be 0 and one would get the same *average*.